# copying files from a remote server

Tags: file, ssh, copy

I'm trying to copy a file from a remote server via ssh.

Basically I'm doing this

```
scp user@server:path/to/file /home/luis/test/
```

But I get this error:

```
target '/home/luis/test/' is not a directory
```

Comment: Then, probably, it is not a directory. What is the output of `ls -ld /home/luis/test`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov drwxr-xr-x 2 luis luis 4096 Mai 11 12:03 /home/luis/test

Comment: You need to run this command on your computer and not on the server.